# How do I override a property in typescript?

Tags: typescript

This may not be possible due to current language limitations, but I'm using the latest TS (1.8.10) and am running into an issue with the ui-grid typings.  The `isRowSelectable` property on `IGridOptions` is defined as an optional boolean but the documentation says it's a function (and it is).  I am trying to override the boolean property to be a function that returns a boolean.

Normally, I just extend the typing interface and do what I need, but that's not working in this case.  Here's what I have:

```
interface ISelectionGridOptions extends IGridOptions {
  isRowSelectable: (row: IGridRowOf<Profile>) => boolean;
}
```

Where the relevant field in `IGridOptions` is:

```
export interface IGridOptions {
  ...
  isRowSelectable?: boolean
  ...
}
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
(41,11): error TS2430: Interface 'ISelectionGridOptions' incorrectly extends interface 'IGridOptionsOf<any>'.
  Types of property 'isRowSelectable' are incompatible.
    Type '(row: IGridRowOf<Profile>) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Short of fixing the core typings definitions, is there a way to fix this in my code?

Comment: If the interface declares `isRowSelectable` to be a boolean then you can not "override" it with a function, because boolean isn't callable.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, it breaks not because the boolean isn't callable, but, like the error says, because a function isn't assignable to boolean. The function peg is failing to fit into the boolean hole, not vice versa.

Comment: **See Also**: [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41285211/1366033)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the type definitions are incorrect, you can't use overriding in order to fix them - the type system correctly treats this as an error. In a typed language, it's a good thing that subclasses are prevented from changing type signatures. The problem here is the broken type definition. If it's not practical to fix the def, and the issue occurs in only a few places in your code, you could use a cast to `any` to disable typechecking until the defs are fixed:

```
var foo = <boolean> (<any>bar).isRowSelectable(args);
bar.isRowSelectable = <any>foo;
```

Just leave a comment explaining what's going on. It is, of course, best to fix the type defs.

> **Note:** It breaks, like the error says, because a function isn't assignable to boolean. The function peg is failing to fit into the boolean hole, not vice versa

Comment: Yea, I did my mitzvah for today and submitted a PR:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/9594

Answer (score 21):

You can use the utility type `Omit`:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk

```
interface ISelectionGridOptions extends Omit<IGridOptions, 'isRowSelectable'> {
  isRowSelectable: (row: IGridRowOf<Profile>) => boolean;
}
```

Comment: IMO, this is not the right answer or solution.  Sure, it's a workaround, but it doesn't address or fix the root cause of the problem which is something I would encourage any engineer to pursue.

Comment: Agree it doesn't solve the OP's issue, but this is extremely useful for code-reuse, especially if you want to re-use something from a third party. +1

Answer (score 5):

#### Update for TS 3.5+

You can add this utility type to your project:

```
type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;
```

And then use it like this:

```
type ISelectionGridOptions = Modify<IGridOptions, {
  isRowSelectable: (row: IGridRowOf<Profile>) => boolean;
}>
```

[**Demo in TS Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwJYDMQB4AqAaKAlAPigF4oB5AWyWC1wGsIQ4V8iAyfAbgFgAoPiADsArhSgBJAMYQAwgCcIAQzEBvPlA1QAaosFIANvsXZ1mmQAs4kuEeAQTvTVADKwOYoDuAIwhy5IPgBfPj5QSCgABV8AZzhBADE5OAoAGSQvd38SKDVHTRQkOWjgADllCAAuKGK5JEEAcx48jSNisopK6rc6xtMNFEUANzhauylZBWUqmp6m4P5eMOgZYWLkqKK47PhkNHQN2ISk1PTMkFxcpwHh0Yhx+SUKKvvJijmCEN5rQWKoChADnEqis1hRAYJspd8oU2uUqgByADSIH0EHhDicrVKcKg8Jg1HRfSg1xG1Du0geUwkFNeADodHpDIogp9vrFUbT9HB6gAKf7ggCUnCAA)

#### Further Reading

- [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41285211/1366033)
- [How to override type properties in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43080547/1366033)

Comment: This is available in the excellent `type-fest` package as `Merge`.

Comment: @rattray, cool!  I think that comment would actually be a decent answer itself if you wanted to add it as its own answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Merge` utility from the excellent `type-fest` package to override or overwrite any property on a type, regardless of it's original type:

```
import type {Modify} from 'type-fest'

type SelectionGridOptions = Modify<GridOptions, {
  isRowSelectable: (row: GridRow<Profile>) => boolean;
}>
```