# How to override type properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

For example, I have

```
type Line = {
  start: Point;
  end: Point;
  color: string; //'cyan'/'aquablue'/...
}
```

But now I want to create new line type on the base of Line, so that it stores color as number:

```
type HexColorLine = Point & {
  color: number;
}
```

Now I expect the HexColorPoint type be equal to

```
{
  start: Point;
  end: Point;
  color: number;
}
```

But it equals to

```
{
  start: Point;
  end: Point;
  color: string | number;
}
```

Is there a way to **override** but not extend the prop type **with some short syntax**? Do i really have to define entirely new type for this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't override like you are trying to do. You could instead declare a `SimpleLine` without the color property, and then declare `Line` and `HexColorLine` as extending the `SimpleLine`? Is there some reason I'm missing that you can't do this?

Comment: See also: [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file) and [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Create a helper type:

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;
```

Usage:

```
type HexColorLine = Overwrite<Line, { color: number }>
```

Comment: Is this still valid for TypeScript v3.9?

Comment: This can be written today as `type Overwrite<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;`

Comment: I have a problem with that solution: it lets me add arbitrary properties. I want to have an error of I'm overwriting a property name that doesn't exist...

Answer (score 22):

A simple one off solution as of TypeScript 3.5 could be:

```
type HexColorLine = Omit<Line, 'color'> & {
  color: number;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In TypeScript 3.5 or later you can use [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys).

For types:

```
type HexColorPoint = Omit<Line, "color"> & {
    color: number;
}
```

For interfaces:

```
interface HexColorPoint extends Omit<Line, "color"> {
    color: number;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To expand on [Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64968854/1431452) which uses Omit, you can do the following to make a more generic utility type.

```
type Overwrite<Base, Overrides> = Omit<Base, keyof Overrides> & Overrides


type HexColorLine = Overwrite<Line, { color: number }>
```

This omits all of the keys in the provided `Overrides` type from the `Base` type, then combines that with the provided `Overrides`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported at the moment. TypeScript would need a concept of subtraction types. Proposals exist https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183

## Fix

Create a base type :

```
type LineBase = {
  start: Point;
  end: Point;
}
type LineBase = LineBase & {
  color: string; //'cyan'/'aquablue'/...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I had type where I needed to narrow the type on a property and this works.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type Override<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U

type ColorNumber =  {
  color: number;
}

type HexColorPoint = Override<
  Line,
  ColorNumber
> // --> {start: Point; end: Point; color: number}
```

I assume you wanted to do

```
type HexColorLine = Line & {
  color: number;
}
```

instead of

```
type HexColorLine = Point /* <-- typo? */ & {
  color: number;
}
```

With Typescript >2.8 i was able to override like this:

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html :

> We did not include the Omit type because it is trivially written
>   as Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>.

```
// So we define Omit -.-
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

// Sidenote: 
// keyof is just getting all the keys for a given type separeted by |
// keyof Line --> 'start' | 'end' | 'color'

// And we define Override which unions the type without unwanted keys and the 
// type defining the new keys
type Override<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U

// just define which properties you want to redefine 
// and remove "Point &" as it will be done in the Override type
type HexColorLine =  {
  color: number;
}
type HexColorPoint = Override<
  Line,
  HexColorLine
> // --> {start: Point; end: Point; color: number}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Override` from the `utility-types` package https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#overwritet-u.
So in the future maybe you would like to use other cool helpers from there.