# Typescript generic constraint for type with only properties from another type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a `Overwrite` type that can overwrite an existing type's properties with a different type. For instance:

```
type TypeA = { prop1: string; prop2: number };

type OverwrittenType = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop1: number; prop2: string }>;
// OverwrittenType is now equivalent to { prop1: number; prop2: string }
```

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975267/11096668) which does the job nicely, however it's a bit too permissive for my liking, as it allows you to replace properties that were never in the original type to begin with.

```
type TypeA = { prop1: string; prop2: number };

type OverwrittenType = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop1: number; prop3: string }>;
// OverwrittenType is now equivalent to { prop1: number; prop2: number; prop3: string }
```

Below is the `Overwrite` type from that other thread.

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;
```

How do I need to modify it to prohibit replacement keys that are not present in the initial type?

```
type TypeA = { prop1: string; prop2: number };

type OverwrittenType = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop1: number; prop3: string }>; // Throw some sort of error here, prop3 is not a key of TypeA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition on you generic !

```
type Overwrite<T extends { [key in keyof U]: any }, U> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;

type TypeA = { prop1: string; prop2: number };

type OverwrittenType = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop1: number }>;  // ok
const foo: OverwrittenType = { prop1: 3, prop2: 3 }

type OverwrittenType2 = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop3: number }>;  // error 
const bar: OverwrittenType = { prop1: 3, prop3: 3 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgd0QS2BAPAFShAD0wDsATAZygG8oBtAawhCjWKkZAHsAzKAVQC6ALigBDYswC%20AGn4A%20KAF5YAWwy5ZHHvKgAyfgG4AUEdCQoOcBACCS6lDCJOYAIwjywdMQDmBh07AAJhFiAFcVACMkKEljUytYBBR0YBJLc2V4JFQMbHSbWRpHZzcoMMjoyTk-KAB6WqhOeiMAY05iDyhuTk4RLOSMNITlIoDSgGZZYqCRcZiTM2h%20nNSIYnzAu2WUvKtrQv9ncZDwqMQY6qg6hqQnc9b2zojRRD6klaGM%202mJqYDjqBzSQmIA)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't flesh out my example enough. This solution only works as well as the original solution in the case where you are overwriting both a real and not real property. I've modified my example to include a type change to prop1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a mapped type like this:

```
type TypeA = { prop1: string; prop2: number };

type Overwrite<T, U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>> = { [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends U[Key] ? T[Key] : U[Key] };

type OverwrittenTypeWorks = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop2: string }>; //  { prop1: string, prop2: string }
type WrongOverwrittenType = Overwrite<TypeA, { prop3: string }>; // Throw some sort of error here, prop3 is not a key of TypeA
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8pgE4HswEYAuKAZ2CwEsA7AcwG5NcwAmYqgVwFsAjCLKAL50AUMNCQoAeQBufAO6VgEADwwANFACqUCAA8lVACYkoABQCGWYBXMAbZQCUIAYxxZDygNYQQOAGawGuZUIAB84SjoUADaANI%20UNRQ3r4BMAC6xOxGEH7UEIY6%20hBGJppxPulQAPywFSBVxOXxDYIiYvBSslgKFMAGcJAA6m6eJqgy8ooqg4gaGNh4rKTk1DSCoQwA9FtQUYsExGSUtBoHy8drgh0SQ7i0kz2KA50T3b1KqvAI84x4AMxHVa0DbbXYwAAWuDkpBwnGgJDcwCg-h0WFw-AhfAgZyY-0SJioOGR5mSCVRswQQA)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't flesh out my example enough. This solution only works as well as the original solution in the case where you are overwriting both a real and not real property. I've modified my example to include a type change to prop1 as well.